# Mavericks: brew install scipy -- okay, brew test scipy -- failure

Tags: python, installation, scipy, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I followed the suggestion [here](https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/) for installing SciPy on Mavericks and ran:

```
brew install python3

pip3 install virtualenv nose

brew install numpy --with-python3
brew install scipy --with-python3

brew test numpy
brew test scipy
```

and didn't run into any trouble until the last command, which produced:

```
Testing scipy
==> python -c import scipy; assert not scipy.test().failures
Python version 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
nose version 1.3.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
Error: scipy: failed
Failed executing: python -c import\ scipy;\ assert\ not\ scipy.test().failures
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:585:in `system'
/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-python/scipy.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Scipy>'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/language/python.rb:25:in `call'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/language/python.rb:25:in `block in each_python'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/language/python.rb:17:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/language/python.rb:17:in `each_python'
/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-python/scipy.rb:77:in `block in <class:Scipy>'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:509:in `block in run_test'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/fileutils.rb:21:in `mktemp'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:507:in `run_test'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/test.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in test'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/test.rb:58:in `block in test'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/test.rb:37:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/test.rb:37:in `test'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:136:in `<main>'
```

And when I open `python3` and type `import scipy; scipy.test()` I get hundreds of errors and dozens of failed tests:

```
FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=276, SKIP=920, errors=326, failures=42)
<nose.result.TextTestResult run=16412 errors=326 failures=42>
```

What did I do wrong? I had previously installed a bunch of software (like Python), then uninstalled everything and started over, but probably didn't do it so cleanly. Can I salvage this without reinstalling Mavericks?

Meanwhile, Homebrew installed GCC 4.9 as a dependency of NumPy, but that output suggests I'm still using whatever I had installed with XCode. This could be a separate issue, but `gcc -v` gives me:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

The reason I mention it is that I'd like to know if I caused a bigger problem with my system.

Comment: comment: just don't follow that suggestion. install either anaconda python or enthought canopy, that ship scipy

Comment: @GiulioGhirardo I want to use Homebrew

Comment: Fair enough. May I ask you why?

Comment: @GiulioGhirardo I just like having everything in one place. I came from using Windows a few months ago and Program Files is always in the back of my mind. But I've been thinking about it more since your comment and I might be changing my mind. Either way I'm reformatting this week in advance of Yosemite so maybe this won't matter

Comment: Please report this to the scipy issue tracker; this reflects a bug in scipy. If you simply "pip install scipy" do you see something similar?

Also, you said: "Meanwhile, Homebrew installed GCC 4.9 as a dependency of NumPy, but that output suggests I'm still using whatever I had installed with XCode."

This is normal; GCC installed by Homebrew is named gcc-4.9.

Answer (score 2):

These errors are spurious and may be ignored. This will be fixed in an upcoming release of scipy. The scipy issue explaining this problem is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3853

The Homebrew-python scipy formula now applies the same fix that scipy will apply in the next release; after `brew update && brew reinstall scipy`, `brew test scipy` will pass.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue using Python 2.7. I've tried a couple of different things:

- creating a soft link named "gcc" to gcc-4.9 in /usr/local/bin so that
  the brewed version shows up when I do a `which gcc`

  `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/local/bin/gcc`
- telling brew to use the default FORTRAN flags:

  `brew install scipy --default-fortran-flags`

I'm still getting the same error as the one you describe in response to `brew test scipy`. Running numpy's test suite produced no errors.